# How to run parallel threads that stop once the quickest thread finishes (C, pthreads or openmp)

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, pthreads, openmp

I'm trying to find a way to run multiple socket clients in parallel; such that once the first client receives a valid response - the code continues running and stops the still running threads.

My use case is for a client device that has a single server device it's trying to communicate with - however the path to that device can take 1 to 5 different paths (roaming wireless network with multiple gateways).

My code currently supports this by serially attempting multiple IPs until it connects but this is painfully slow when it has to wait for the first 4 connections to fail. However, I'm struggling with pthreads since I have yet to find a way to cancel other threads without disastrous consequences.

Heres some psuedo code:

```
    //psuedo code

    char host[5][100];
    strcpy(host[0], "IP0");
    strcpy(host[1], "IP1");
    strcpy(host[2], "IP2");
    strcpy(host[3], "IP3");
    strcpy(host[4], "IP4");

    spawn5Threads()
    {
        data = getDataFromTCPSocket(host[myThreadIndex]);

        if(data.valid)
        {
            cancelAllOtherThreads();
        }
    }

    if(data.valid)
    {
        sendDataToBeProcessed(data);
    }
    else
    {
        //fail!
    }
```

Comment: Well, the ugliest thing comes to mind - let the winning thread close the sockets of all other threads :D

Comment: but indeed, perhaps this would have been done *easier* without threads and just using `select`?

Comment: However you do it, you need to be really careful with race conditions where two threads end such that both would wind up calling your `sendDataToBeProcessed()` function.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala can you elaborate on select?

Comment: @AndrewHenle agreed - pthread_mutex would be used around a global valid flag

Comment: [`select(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html). It would be especially simple if you can do just say one HTTP request/response with each socket

Comment: OpenMP and pthreads are vastly different. Please narrow down which you intend to use - or if your question is agnostic, remove both of those tags. Otherwise this hurts the question by making it very broad.

Comment: The moment one thread connects, signal all other threads. If they were blocked in a call to `connect` they'd returned `-1` and set `errno` to `EINTR`.

Comment: @killthebabysitter: In addition to the manpage of select(), also do 'man select_tut'. And on Linux, for high-performance applications, epoll is in some cases much better than select/pselect.